# Deploy node server on heroku and receive "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a server written in node.js using node 6.10.2 and ecmascript. I want to upload it to heroku, locally when i rung the server with "npm start" the server starts without a problem, but on heroku I recevied the following error

```
import express from 'express';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Use `require()` instead of `import`
2. Transpile your code

Node doesn't support the `import` keyword. In Node you import modules with the `require()` function. For example you can change this:

```
import express from 'express';
```

to this:

```
const express = require('express');
```

Or you can transpile the code e.g. with Babel if you really want to use `import`. See:

- https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why it's work locally and on heroku machine doesn't work.